# How to can create routers without adding index.php or using .htacess Slim framework

Tags: php, router, slim-lang

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\app;

$app-> get('/' ,function(){
echo "Hello There";
});

$app-> get('/h' ,function(){
    echo "Heloow word 2";
    });

$app->run();
```

Output

```
in the main page " / "
```

it functions as normal outputting `Hello There`

but when I go to `/h`
It gives this error

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

[image]

I have to go to `index.php/h`  for it to work
can I remove the `index.php` and just type /h in the URL ?

without using `.htacess` ?

Comment: A web server serves files by mapping the URL to files and folders on the disk. If a mapping doesn’t exist, and you want to perform custom logic, you need to tell the server that, and for Apache servers, that’s what htaccess is for. For Nginx, you’d do this in the conf, in IIS you’d do this in web.config, and when using the PHP binary you’d specify the router script. When can’t you use server config, such as htaccess?

Comment: If you don't want to configure your web server to map all requests to one single PHP script, you'll have to create as many PHP scripts as routes, which quite diminishes the value of using a framework. I think you should edit the question and explain your actual problem rather than the solution you figured out (skipping server configuration).